# Cannot update taskDetails in Microsoft Graph Explorer

Tags: rest, web-applications, microsoft-graph-api

**What I'm attempting:**

Following the documentation for [Update taskDetails](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/taskdetails_update) on the [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer), I am attempting a PATCH request on:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/tasks/{Id}/details
```

**Request header:**

```
Content-type: application/json
Prefer: "return=represent"
If-Match: {@odata.etag from a successful prior GET on taskDetails}
```

**Request Body:**

```
{
  "description": "My new description",
  "previewType": "description",
  "references": {},
  "checklist": {}
}
```

**Response:**

```
client-request-id: {some Id}
content-type: application/json
cache-control: private
request-id: {some Id}
Status Code: 412     <--- Pre-condition not met!
{
    "error": {
        "code": "UnknownError",
        "message": "",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "{some Id}",
            "date": "{date}"
        }
    }
}
```

Using the Chrome Developer Tools to parse the **Response Headers**:

```
HTTP/1.1 412 Precondition Failed
Cache-Control: private
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json
request-id: {some Id}
client-request-id: {some Id}
x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"West US","Slice":"SliceB","ScaleUnit":"002","Host":"AGSFE_IN_1","ADSiteName":"WST"}}
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: ETag, Location, Preference-Applied, Content-Range, request-id, client-request-id
Duration: 68.3028
Date: {date}
```

**A note on Planner**

The weird thing is, it appears that Planner uses a completely different API to update taskDetails, and there is no documentation for said API.

Any help would be appreciated; this is an enterprise deployment of programmatic Planner access within our workflow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

12 hours after I posted the question, Microsoft pushed a big update to the Graph Planner API. The issue is now resolved.

The process to update a task description is:

- GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/planner/tasks/{taskId}/details
- Grab the @odata.etag from the response
- PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/planner/tasks/{taskId}/details with:

**Headers**:

```
If-Match: {etag}
```

**Payload**:

```
{
  "description": "Your new description"
}
```

The key is to use the etag from the taskDetails object, **not** the task object.